# Django static ファイルが読み込めません

Tags: python, django

諸事情により、サーバーの再インストールを行い再構築を行っていたのですが、Djangoのstaticファイルの読み込みができません。

<環境について>
・GMO Cloud VPS
・CentOS8
・nginx
・Django 2.2
・python3.6
・仮想環境 venv

<settings.py>

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/[ User ]/Django/[file]/[ project name ]/[ app name ]/static/'
```

<nginx .conf>

```
location /static {
    root /home/[ User ]/Django/[file]/[ project name ]/[ app name ]/static;
    }
```

<ツリー>

```
.
├── [Project Name]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── [ App Name ]
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── media
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   └── images
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── manage.py
```

再インストール前までは、問題なく読み込んでいたのですが、再設定後から一切読み込まれなくなりました。
必要な情報などございましたら、お知らせくださいませ。

Answer (score 1):

いろいろと試したところ、解決しました。

#### 結論

パーミッションの問題にて解決

#### 解決に至るまでの経緯

nginxのエラーログを見直したところ「13:Permission denied」があることに気が付きパーミッションの見直しを試みたところ解決。

#### 解決方法

全てのルートディレクトリに実行権限を与えた。

```
sudo chmod +x /home
sudo chmod +x /home/[ User ]
sudo chmod +x /home/[ User ]/Django
sudo chmod +x /home/[ User ]/Django/[file]/[ project name ]
sudo chmod +x /home/[ User ]/Django/[file]/[ project name ]/[ app name ]
```

上記にて、staticファイルが無事に読み込まれるようになりました。

解決に向けご尽力くださいました皆様に改めてお礼を申し上げます。
考えてみると初歩的なミスといったところでした。

今後は、エラーログなどしっかりと見ながら開発をしていくこととさせていただきます。
お騒がせいたしました。